# Calling struct pointer member from Class - (pointer) "...uninitialized", (pointer) "...was declared here"

Tags: c++, class, struct, arduino, arduino-c++

I am attempting to develop a "wrapper" Class that integrates multiple peripherals in a controller board including sensors, RGB LEDs an many others.

To achieve this, I am trying to group all connected peripherals in a structure inside the *Controller* Class and access its members through a struct pointer.

My end goal is to declare a controller and use the peripherals as follows:

```cpp
    Controller sys;
    sys.devices -> rgb.setColor(/*color code*/);
```

since I find it more readable/understandable during development.

I have reduced my code to the bare minimum after several corrections based on other SOVF posts.

Please note that I am testing my code in Codelite using mingw64, however this will be implemented using platformio on a Teensy board. This is just a skimmed version for the forum

Physical pins are declared as a struct, in a pinout.h file:

```cpp
#ifndef PINOUT_H
#define PINOUT_H

struct Pinout {

    int R = 1;
    int G = 2;
    int B = 3;
};

#endif // PINOUT_H
```

then, there is an *RGBLed* class and a main file (I put them together here just for the sake of simplicity)

```cpp
#include "pinout.h"
#include <iostream>

class RGBLed
{

public:
    
    RGBLed(int pinR, int pinG, int pinB)
    {
        this->_r = pinR;
        this->_g = pinG;
        this->_b = pinB;
    };
    
    // this is just a dumb example method
    bool turnOn()
    {

        this->_ledState = true;

        return _ledState;
    }

    int* getPinout()
    {

        static int pinPtr[3];

        pinPtr[0] = this->_r;
        pinPtr[1] = this->_g;
        pinPtr[2] = this->_b;

        return pinPtr;
    }

private:
    int _r, _g, _b;
    bool _ledState;
};

/* This is the _wrapper_ Class I am designing */
class Controller
{

public:
    // Default Constructor
    inline Controller(){};

    struct Peripherals {
        
        RGBLed rgb = RGBLed(_pins->R, _pins->G, _pins->B);
       // on a previous compilation I used:
       //  RGBLed rgb = RGBLed(Controller::_pins->R, Controller::_pins->G, Controller::_pins->B);
       // however I ran into linker issues

       /* In the future many more devices will be declared here */
    };

    struct Peripherals *devices;

private:
    // I want to keep the pins unreachable to the developer (aka myself and colleagues)
    static Pinout* _pins;       // I initially had a warning of "invalid use of non-static data member"
                                // after declaring it as static it went away
};
```

Then, my *main()* is:

```cpp
int main()
{

    // Controller object instance
    Controller sys;

    // Testing if we can call methods from the struct member inside the Class
    if(sys.devices->rgb.turnOn())
        std::cout << "LED is ON" << std::endl;
        
    // Retrieve pinout
    int* conn = sys.devices->rgb.getPinout();

    std::cout << "RGBLed pins are: " << std::endl;

    for(int idx = 0; idx < 3; idx++) {

        //std::cout << std::to_string(conn[idx]);

        if(idx != 2)
            std::cout << ", ";
        else
            std::cout << " " << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If I comment the lines: `int* conn = sys.devices->rgb.getPinout();` and `std::cout << std::to_string(conn[idx]);` my code compiles just fine and, evidently, I don't get any valuable output.

[image]

**However**, if I call the `.getPinout()` method from the *rgb* object inside the struct, I get the warnings:

*"main.cpp...warning: 'sys.Controller::devices' is used uninitialized"*

and

*"main.cpp...note: sys.Controller::devices was declared here " pointing at the line: `Controller sys;"*

I am absolutely certain that I might be butchering the C++ language hence I am asking here for some *pointers* (pun intended). I have mixed too many solutions I have found here in SOVF without any success.

What is the best way to compartmentalize my peripherals through a struct inside the Class?
Is there a possibility that on top of my own mistakes, I am also facing compiler issues due to the mismatch between gcc (using 13) and the Arduino gcc compiler?

**EDITS:**

Based on the comments from @273K and @KIIV I realised that effectively I was missing the initialization of the struct *devices* since I was declaring *only* a pointer with nothing in it.

Now, I am facing another rather minor issue, I guess.

I am unable to access the elements from the *pinout* struct. Please see above how they are initialised inside of the struct declaration

If I do this inside the Controller class, where the RGBLed receives numerical values

```cpp
class Controller
{

public:
    // Default Constructor
    inline Controller(){};

    struct Peripherals {

        RGBLed rgb = RGBLed(1, 2, 3) ; // <--- pay attention to this line
    };

    Peripherals devs, *devices = &devs;

    // devices = &devs;
    // devices = malloc(sizeof(Peripherals)); // = new Peripherals{RGBLed(_pins->R, _pins->G, _pins->B)};

private:
    static Pinout* _pins; // I initially had a warning of "invalid use of non-static data member"
};
```

I can successfully print the pinout:

[image]

**However** I am unable to access the predefined values inside the pinout struct.

If inside the struct Peripherals I do:

`RGBLed rgb = RGBLed(Controller::_pins->R, 2, 3);`

I get:

_*"undefined reference to Controller::*pins"**

I am attempting to indicate that the scope is from the Class *Controller*

I have also tried moving the Pinout pointer inside of the Peripherals struct and changing the calling to the pins as:

`RGBLed rgb = RGBLed(this->_pins->R, 2, 3);`

getting a similar error _"undefined reference to Controller::Peripherals::*pins"*

Is it even possible to access the private member this way?

Comment: May I ask where you initialize `Controller::devices`?

Comment: devices is declared as pointer, but constructor does nothing at all with it, therefore it'll contain random trash and you are trying to use that trash as a pointer...

Comment: @273K and KIIV, thanks for your comments. You guys are absolutely right! However, I am not there, yet. I have added an EDIT at the bottom of my post in response to your comments

Comment: Don't post a second question in an existing one, ask a new question in a new post, with a [mcve] by removing irrelevant code.

Comment: @273K Apologies. Will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @273K and @KIIV's comments, I realised that I was not declaring and initialising the pointer *devices* to the struct *Peripherals*.

The corrected *Controller* Class is the following:

```cpp
class Controller
{

public:
    // Default Constructor
    inline Controller(){};

    struct Peripherals {

        RGBLed rgb = RGBLed(ledPins.R, ledPins.G, ledPins.B);
        /* More devices to be added */
    } devs;

    Peripherals *devices = &devs;

};
```

where I redeclared the Pinout struct as:

```cpp
 struct Pinout {

     int R = 1;
     int G = 2;
     int B = 3;

} ledPins;    // <-- predeclaring the struct object
```

This way, I avoided unnecessary nesting of structs and I can use the Pinout object in the RGBLed constructor.

I can finally run my code without a problem:

[image]

Despite I am not a big fan of having two Peripherals objects accessible in the *main()* function (*devs* and the pointer *devices*), it is fine for now. I really wanted to have only ONE object to get access to all the peripherals - the pointer *devices*.

Thanks to all who helped!

:Beers: